# Can I change OS from Widows 8.1 Pro to Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-8

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Z500 running Windows 8.1 pro but get many problems such as "Reset your Pc not working "Insert Media Some files are missing. Your windows installation or recovery medial will provide these files". This is a frequent occurrence. I have tried reinstalling and repairing but the same problem arises. Microsoft's answer to this is: How to create installation media for a PC refresh or reset http://windows.microsoft.com/en-IN/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media but I can't do this as I don't have a PC running Windows 7. There is also the problem of so many unwanted adverts on Windows 8 that I get frustrated at times as othe time consuming problems arise.
A computer savvy friend suggests I change the OS to Linux 12.04, so I ask do you have experience of this and is the OS compatible with the Z500. Is it a simple uninstall Windows 8 and install Linux or are there complications?

Failing that do I downgrade to Windows 7 (at more cost) or can you recommend some other option. Windows 8 is totally spoiled because of all the intrusive adverts, especially on XBox.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Answer (score 1):

all you have to do is go to http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop
Then download one of the versions there, either 12.04 Long Term Support, or the last version (I recomend 64-Bit in each case).

or go to http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/
download the USB installer, connect a thumb drive, then look for the image you already downloaded in the first step I told you, and create your Bootable USB.

Once that is done, restart your pc and press whatever button gives you access to the boot menu (it depends on the machine but in most cases one of the F keys gives you access to that), and then follow the instructions to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The Lenovo Ideapad Z500 is not listed on the Ubuntu certified hardware list.  Several Lenovo Thinkpad models are however, and the specs are very similar.

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/

No you do not need to downgrade to Windows 7 to install Ubuntu, but it may not be as simple to install on a laptop that came pre-installed with Windows 8.  Have you tried to restore Windows 8 to factory default?  Mine came with a small partition (reserved piece of the hard drive) for that purpose.
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/restore-refresh-reset-pc